# codeigniter: how to perform mathematical operations using two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, math, operation

i have two arrays like this

array 1

```
array(3) { [0]=> float(2.7742631687417) [1]=> float(2.5949809043991) [2]=> float(3.0174025996932) }
```

array 2

```
array(3) { [0]=> float(2.7259998526469) [1]=> float(3.4826656582587) [2]=> float(3.2284968891602) }
```

**This array is dynamic** , so the size of the array is not always the array ( 3 ) . sometimes array has a size of array ( 2 ) , array ( 4 ) , array ( 5 ) . **The array just as an example** .

I want to perform mathematical operations using the values ​​in the array using the looping function . The mathematical formula if I do it manually is like this

for example:

`V1 = 2.7742631687417 / (2.7742631687417 + 2.7259998526469)`

`V2 = 2.5949809043991 / (2.5949809043991 + 3.4826656582587)`

`V3 = 3.0174025996932 / (3.0174025996932 + 3.2284968891602)`

The numerical values ​​obtained from the existing values ​​in the array. "V" number depends on how many number of indexes that exist on the array . eg array ( 3 ) then "V" totaling 3 as well (V1, V2, V3).

so how I can perform mathematical operations and store it into the array as well ? I use PHP and CodeIgniter

Comment: If you got your answer, please pick one and close the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, it seems that you want to divide the value of array1 to the summation of the value of array1 and array2. The code would be:

```
 $arrlength = count($arr1);
    for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
       $arr3[$x]=$arr1[$x]/($arr1[$x]+$arr2[$x]);
            }
```

Comment: I already follow the algorithm of you but the result is not as I expected . I do not know why
the result I get is like this

`array(3) { [0]=> float(0.50438736437759) [1]=> float(0.42697134123315) [2]=> float(0.48310136995931) }`

and the value array should I get is like this

`array(3) { [0]=> float(0,495612636) [1]=> float(0,573028659) [2]=> float(0,51689863) }`  @GoodLuck

Comment: You are probably dividing array2 to the summation of array1 and areay2 instead of dividing array1 to the summation of these two arrays.

Answer (score 2):

here is what you have written in your example arrays so this is dynamic if you create a function and pass 2 array with any length it will calculate and store it in another array called $r here.

```
      $a = array(2.7742631687417,2.5949809043991,3.0174025996932);
     $b= array(2.7259998526469,3.4826656582587,3.2284968891602);

     for($i=0; $i<count($a);$i++){
          $r[] = $a[$i] / ($a[$i] + $b[$i]);
     }
     print_r($r);
```

Regards